# What's the most efficient way to generate thumbnails?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, thumbnails

I am developing a graphical application, and I need to keep a thumbnail for each page.
The challenge is how to generate a thumbnail file without loosing performance ??

Currently here is my code to do it:

```
VisualBrush VisualBrush = new VisualBrush(pageToGenerateThumbnailFor);
UIVisual.Background = VisualBrush;

RenderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)UIVisual.ActualWidth, (int)UIVisual.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

rtb.Render(UIVisual);

using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(ThumbFileFullPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
   PngBitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
   pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
   pngEncoder.Save(outStream);
}
```

So, Is there a faster way to generate a thumbnail for a given Visual ?

Thanks

Comment: How many images do you have, how often to they change, etc? These factors will likely affect the correct answer

Comment: See http://imageresizing.net/ for a good solution and see http://www.nathanaeljones.com/blog/2009/20-image-resizing-pitfalls for some good information on image resizing in general

Comment: Number of images may vary, I don't know how users will use it, but, as for change, its just when user re-size, rotate or move an image

Answer (score 3):

I did a bit of research recently for generating Image Thumbnails on the fly for an eCommerce site. I started off doing this myself generating a bitmap and then resizing etc. similar to the answer above. After problems with image size on disc and quality I looked in to http://imageresizing.net/ and I haven't looked back since. It can generate images from byte(), streams and physicals files all very quickly with one line of code:

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(New MemoryStream(bImage), sImageLocation + sFullFileName, New      ResizeSettings("maxwidth=214&maxheight=238"))
```

I would definitely recommend this component rather than trying to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: This is a solution for web application, but, what we have is a desktop application ..

Comment: Hi Samir, this will work in WPF application without problem. I even call it on a scheduled windows service.

Comment: imageresizing is NOT FREE - there are licenses etc. involved and if all you want to do is get some thumbnails of decent quality with decent performance there are plenty ways to do this using just the framework and no third party libraries (and costs) getting involved.

Comment: This is 10 years old @LordWabbit...

Comment: @James - and yet oddly enough it's still relevant, and may assist people who are looking for a solution.  How did your reply help anything?

Answer (score 1):

The following class from a utility library that I've written performs well for me and produces good clear quality thumbnails...

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace Simple {
    public static class ThumbnailCreator {
        private static readonly object _lock = new object();

        public static Bitmap createThumbnail(Stream source, Int32 width, Int32 height) {
            Monitor.Enter(_lock);
            Bitmap output = null;
            try {
                using (Bitmap workingBitmap = new Bitmap(source)) {
                    // Determine scale based on requested height/width (this preserves aspect ratio)
                    Decimal scale;
                    if (((Decimal)workingBitmap.Width / (Decimal)width) > ((Decimal)workingBitmap.Height / (Decimal)height)) {
                        scale = (Decimal)workingBitmap.Width / (Decimal)width;
                    }
                    else {
                        scale = (Decimal)workingBitmap.Height / (Decimal)height;
                    }
                    // Calculate new height/width
                    Int32 newHeight = (Int32)((Decimal)workingBitmap.Height / scale);
                    Int32 newWidth = (Int32)((Decimal)workingBitmap.Width / scale);
                    // Create blank BitMap of appropriate size
                    output = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                    // Create Graphics surface
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(output)) {
                        g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        Rectangle destRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                        // Use Graphics surface to draw resized BitMap to blank BitMap
                        g.DrawImage(workingBitmap, destRectangle, 0, 0, workingBitmap.Width, workingBitmap.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                output = null;
            }
            finally {
                Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

it also retains the original image's aspect ratio.

Comment: Oh MAN! This code looks like it has been decompiled from IL :P Why use `Monitor.Enter` and `Exit` when you have the `lock` keyword?